# listen to install of my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I want to register gcm_id imidiatly after app was install or updated (as gcm_id may change over application or android id) to be able to send user news asap.
I can listen for broadcast `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` if my package is updated. However broadcast for `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL` is deprecated and does not seems to work (have not seen logs with such intent) and broadcast for `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` is never send to newly installed application as stated in docs.
Is there a work around to listen, when my app is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a work around to listen, when my app is installed?

No. Nothing of your app will get control until the user clicks on the launcher icon for one of your activities, or until something else uses an explicit `Intent` to start up one of your components.

Please register for GCM on the first run of your app.